# Python, grabbing all items from a completed dict. getting a memory error

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am currently finishing up on a program that is suppose to parse a xml file and then set it up and then email it. I am almost done with it but I appear to be stuck and could use some assistance. I am trying to get the path attribute "dir" and "file" from the completed dictionary but i am getting a error with it. Here is part of the code that I am currently working on.

Update: I added the dictonary telling me if it its a Directory change or a Filename change a list along side the

```
def formatChangesByAuthor(changesByAuthor): 
    content = ''
    for author, changes in sorted(changesByAuthor.iteritems()):
    authorName = get_author_name( author );
    content += '       ***** Changes By '+authorName+'*****\n\n'
    for change in changes:
        rawDate = change['date']
        dateRepresentation = rawDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
        content += '           Date: '+ dateRepresentation+'\n\n'

        path_change = change['paths']
        path_attribute= change['Attribute_changes']

        finalizedPathInformation = []

        for single_change in path_change:
            for single_output in path_attribute:  
                finalizedPathInformation.append(single_output+single_change)

        content +="           " + str(finalizedPathInformation) + "\n"
```

What I am hoping to get to work is when there are multiple path in paths it will do

filename : test.xml

directory location : /Testforlder/

for some reason it is showing me a memory error. I wonder if i could of wrote the path part better. Here is my error I am getting.

```
    content +="           " + str(finalizedPathInformation) + "\n" MemoryError
```

Now here is part of the xml file if it will help.

```
<log>
<logentry
revision="33185">
<author>glv</author>
<date>2012-08-06T21:01:52.494219Z</date>
<paths>
<path
action="M"
kind="file">/trunk/build.xml</path>
<path
 kind="dir"
 action="M">/trunk</path>
 </paths>
 <msg>PATCH_BRANCH:N/A
 BUG_NUMBER:N/A
 FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A
 OVERVIEW:N/A 
 Testing the system log.
 </msg>
 </log>
```

Now i had the nodeValue saved in the dictionary but for some reason I can't to get the attribute within the nodeValue to see if it has a "dir" or a "file" attribute at all. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong somewhere. Any advice or help would be very appreciated and welcomed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your `path_change` is a list.  Try `path_change[0].getAttribute('kind')`.

I also propose to add debug output (`print path_change` before the call of getAttribute()) to find out more about your data structures.

Of course if there's a list you might want to process all elements in the list, not just the first.  One way to do this could be:

```
...
    for single_change in path_change:
        kind = str(single_change.getAttribute("kind"))
        if kind == 'dir':
            content += '            Directory Location: '
        elif kind == 'file':
            content += '            Filename:  '
        else:
            raise SomeException("kind is neither dir nor file", kind, single_change)
        content += (str(single_change).
                    replace("u'","       \n").
                    replace("[","").
                    replace("',","").
                    replace("']", "\n ") + "\n")
...
```

Comment: How would I be able to get all of them?

also I replaced the str(path_change.getAttribute("kind")) with  path_change[0].getAttribute("kind") == 'dir' But it gives me a error saying 

    if path_change[0].getAttribute("kind") == 'dir':
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'

Comment: Added an example code on how to process a list instead of a single value.  But it's so straight-forward, I'd call it trivial.

Comment: Thank you, But for some off reason its still giving me this error***           

if str(single_change.getAttribute("kind")) == 'dir':
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'***

is there something else I am missing?

Comment: This should work right but for some reason I am still getting a attribute-error

****kind = str(single_change.getAttribute("kind"))
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'
****

Comment: That means that single_change is not an XML element as well but a unicode value (in Python a kind of string).  I guess your assumption on what you get as input is wrong.  It does seem to have been processed already.  Maybe the information about the XML attributes is not even there.  Try using `print` to generate debug output to find out what your values really are.

Comment: In brief:  If you don't have an XML element, you cannot use that `.getAttribute()` method.

Comment: Hmm okay what i did now was I added the attributes with the value "directory location" and "Filename" into the dictonary. and it can does work in a sense will update my code to explain better.